# Solving Multi-dimentional ODE in Python

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, scipy, numerical-methods, ode

I have to solve numerically ODE of 2nd order. The issue is that I need to solve it simultaneously for two objects (in general N objects) and each object has 4 variables (2 dimensions): 2 in position and 2 in velocity. Please see code below to see the example.

When trying to solve it in Python (Scipy) with provided methods I always encounter the error - "raise ValueError("`y0` must be 1-dimensional.")
ValueError: `y0` must be 1-dimensional."

What is required for y0 is something like:

```
array([[[1, 0],
    [0, 1]],

   [[2, 0],
    [0, 2]]])
```

I think it might be possible to do so in Matlab, but I would like to stay with Python. Also, I want to solve it by Runge-Kutta model.

The possible solution is to reshape everything into 1 dimension, reshape it back and return reshaped again, but it is probably not that effective and efficient.

Thank you for your help. Please ask me if something is not clear

Comment: Please provide your current code that is producing the error. Is this relevant? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l_YND1hSUmY

Comment: The solvers in scipy require that you flatten your state space data into a 1-d array.  If an array makes it much easier for you, you can use a small package that I wrote called [`odeinw`](https://github.com/WarrenWeckesser/odeintw).  Either way, you will still have to reformulate your differential equations as a first order system.

Comment: reshape is fast, as that only changes the view and leaves the data in place. Even if it were copying data, the other operations in the ODE function will have a more significant impact.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. Youtube is relavant, but the problem is that u,v in my case are also vectors.